# Django authenticated user logged in as anonymous user

Tags: python, jquery, django

In my Django view, I authenticate and login a user. However, when I check to see if the user is authenticated in another view with request.user.is_anonymous, the user is anonymous.

I have looked at all the other questions related to this, but haven't found anything to help. I am using jQuery/AJAX to post the data to the Django view, but I have checked and the correct data is being sent, so I don't think there is an issue with the frontend.

```
@csrf_exempt
def LoginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return JsonResponse({'logged_in' : 'yes'})
        return JsonResponse({'logged_in' : 'no'})
```

I get the JSON response logged_in : yes in the browser, so the user is authenticated, but is acting as an anonymous logged in user.

Here is the code I used to test if the user is anonymous

```
@csrf_exempt
def ProfileView(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user.username
        else:
            username = request.user.is_anonymous

        try:
            user = Profile.objects.get(username=username)
            name = user.name
            age = user.age
            return JsonResponse({'name' : name, 'age' : age})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error' : username})
```

Comment: Have you added [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) to your middleware in `settings.py`? Also, why are you writing your own `LoginView`?

Comment: What do you mean, "is acting as an anonymous logged in user"? Where is that? How is it being demonstrated?

Comment: I just checked and the AuthenticationMiddleware is added to my settings.py. I am using my own login view because I am trying to create a phonegap app with a django backend. Is there a way to use django LoginView with phonegap?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I used to test for the anonymous user. When I call the request to ProfileView on the frontend, I get the error json response with true for is_anonymous

Comment: The way django keeps track of logged users is via the session. When a user logs in, a session is created and the session_id is passed back by the view in a cookie. In a phone gap app, you have to subsequently pass the session id in every request, otherwise django has no idea which user is sending the request.

Comment: Okay, thank you dirkgroten! Do you know of any resources that would give me an idea of how to do that?

Comment: sorry, updated my comment. in a normal browser, the ajax request would process the cookie and use it automatically in subsequent requests automatically. I don't know how phone gap does it.

Comment: I'm not sure how phone gap does it either, I'll have to do more research. I'm grateful to know that it wasn't something as simple as a mistake in the Django view though

Comment: maybe there's just a setting in phone gap to tell it to honour cookies (store them and send them).

Comment: I will definitely check on that, I'm sure there's more info now that I know what to look for

Comment: [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-discuss/blob/master/FAQ.md) seems to indicate that cordova handles cookies the normal way, so I don't know why it wouldn't just work. Maybe you can check in your debug tools of your phone gap app (chrome?) whether cookies are received/sent correctly. You can see that in the "Network" tab, selecting "XHR" to see ajax requests only.

Comment: also, have you added `django.contrib.sessions` to your installed apps and the session middleware in the middleware settings? (should be by default)

Comment: Now that I know there isn't a problem in my view, the problem could be in the frontend, or the communication between both servers. I might be in a little over my head with this project.